# MUI Grid spacing causes grid to have padding left

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a grid with a bunch of elements but there seems to be a problem when I add spacing to the elements. Here's a picture with `spacing={0}` on the `Grid` container:
[Grid container with no spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDm3s.png)

Here's the result when adding spacing :
[Grid container with spacing = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHdq.png)

I am trying to keep the grid  the same width as the buttons above (see picture). I tried different solutions but it does not seem to work on my side. Here is my code :

```
 return (
<Grid
  sx={{
    width: "100vw",
    overflowX: "hidden",
    padding: { xs: "20px", md: "50px" },
    margin: 0,
    background: "hsl(0, 0%, 98%)",
  }}
  container
>
  <Grid
    sx={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "30px" }}
    item
    display="flex"
    flexWrap={"wrap"}
    justifyContent={"space-between"}
    gap={"25px"}
  >
    <SearchInput />
    <FilterMenu />
  </Grid>

  <Grid container spacing={3} xs={12}>
    {countries?.map((country, idx) => (
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <CountryCard key={idx} country={country} />
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and correct way in my opinion based on your images, would be to separate your `Grid` containers. One Grid containing the Search and Filter inputs and another to contain your flags. In this way you can keep a better control of your spacing and use less css customisations in the `Grid` items. Have a look in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ritchie-36qpc9?file=/demo.js) where i have left a few comments and let me know it it helps.